# Storing matrix data from a text file in a multidimensional array in c

Tags: arrays, c, dynamic-memory-allocation

So, I'll preface this by saying I'm fairly new to pointers and dynamic allocation. Currently I am trying to store a file that contains a 3x3 matrix of ints into a 2d array. I've tried debugging my code and what I notice is that it reads my first 2 values, but than begins to generate random garbage into my 2d array. I assume that I am storing my ints incorrectly and there is a flaw in my logic, but as I keep trying to think about it, I can't seem to find where it could be incorrect as they are moving from [0][0], [0][1], etc.

Here is my code for reference. Thanks, I'd appreciate just some guidance on how I can troubleshoot this problem for this specific case and future issues.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    FILE* fpM1;

    fpM1 = fopen("m1.txt", "r");

    int i, j, row1 = 2, col1 = 2;

    int* ptrM1 = (int* )malloc(9 * sizeof(int));

    if (fpM1 != NULL) {

        for (i = 0; i < row1; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < col1; j++) {

                fscanf(fpM1, "%d", ((ptrM1 + i) + j));

            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < row1; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < col1; j++) {
                {

                    printf(" %d", *((ptrM1 + i) + j));

                }
            }
    }

    free(ptrM1);
    fclose(fpM1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for(i = 0 ; i < 2...` only iterates twice.  If you want to read 3 values, use `for (i=0; i < 3 ...`

Comment: Oh yeah I understand what you mean now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loops end too fast. You should use <= instead of <. After that, everything seems to work perfectly.

Maybe you should consider adding new line in  outer for loop during printing array. It will help with clarity:

```
for (i = 0; i < row1; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < col1; j++) {
    printf(" %d", *(ptrM1 + i));
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

Also you don't need those double brackets before first printf statement. In C you can put many scopes without context, but you shouldn't do that without reason.

EDIT: It actually doesn't work. Reading from file should be done this way:

```
fscanf(fpM1, "%d", ptrM1 + (i * (col1 + 1) + j));
```

and printing:

```
printf(" %d", ptrM1[i * (col1 + 1) + j]);
```

Comment: Gotcha, it seems that by changing this it does in fact iterate the full 9 times now. That makes sense. I still don't understand how it's not storing the ints properly though. I assume my fscanf statement is somehow incorrect.

Comment: I run this on my computer and everything works fine. What do you mean by not storing ints properly? Are you still receiving garbage?

Comment: Well you see I am storing odd numbers 1-17. So my matrix looks like: 1,3,5\n,7,9,11\n,13,15,17. It is skipping over numbers and not storing them within my 2d array.

Comment: Have you corrected both for loops? What is exact output you receiving? As I've said, i just corrected both for loops and it works good on my computer, so your code is correct.

Comment: My output ends up being: 1,7,13,7,13,15,13,15,17. I changed my code on the post for the print statement I realized I didn't add the j for the displaying of the matrix.

Comment: OK, I got it. Sorry for first misleading comment, I've created bad test case. Thats how I done it: `fscanf(fpM1, "%d", ptrM1 + (i * (col1 + 1) + j))`

Comment: The output seems to still be off. You're output comes out as 1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17. When you use those inputs?

Comment: Hmmm, If I may ask what should be the output of this program? I thought that you want to take 3x3 matrix and print it in the same manner on the output. Is that right?

Comment: Yeah exactly, so the specific numbers don't matter. I just want the file to look exactly like it outputs on my console, but somehow the numbers are being jumbled up through the process of scanning and printing.

Comment: So if I understand correctly: input matrix looks like: 1,3,5\n,7,9,11\n,13,15,17 and your output is 1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17? Only difference is lack of \n? If so, you can use my code from main comment (make sure to include EDIT part). If no, please provide more information on what is incorrect.

Comment: Okay, that works. Could you explain the logic behind these two lines you edited? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Of course! So what you are trying to do is to use 1D array (ptrM1) as 2D (in fact, it is just plain, 9 ints long part of memory, just as you allocated this). In order to make second dimension you need to know how long is one row. To navigate through array in 2D you need to settle a row first - that is i * (col1 + 1). It is needed to add 1 to col1 because array starts with 0 and we need to compensate that (you have matrix 3x3 and col1 is only 2). After that you settle column - by adding j.

Comment: Look: i * (col1 + 1) returns first element in each row, j just adds shift in columns. You can make explicit 2D arrays in C, but sometimes it is convenient to simply use 1D as 2D like you did. To make 2D you need to first initialize array of int** (it takes one malloc f.e `int **array = (int**)malloc(10 * sizeof(int**))` and then on each element use malloc (something like this `for(int i =0; i < 10; i++) { array[i] = malloc(sizeof(int*) * 10)}`). If I may ask, please mark my comment as the best answer. I'm still little new and really need this karma points in order to write comments etc.

Comment: Oh! That makes sense. I'll need to study this a bit longer to fully understand it, but I really appreciate your assistance! Cheers.